# ASP.NET Core encoded parameter in route template

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I'm having a route template like this:

```
[HttpGet("{scope}/{id}")]
```

The scope may contain any special characters like `\`. 
When url-encoding the `{scope}` parameter, asp.net core still can't handle it and does not interpret the encoded parameter as parameter but as part of the whole route template. That menas that if I pass `MyController/MyAction/test%2Ftest1/5` it cuts of the `scope` parameter and sets it to `test` instead of `test/test1`.

Why is that like this and how can I prevent asp.net core from doing that?

Comment: It works well when I try your code,do you test in a new web api core 3.0 project?Could you tell us how to reproduce the problem?